# Одинаковы ли .fadeOut() и .css("display","none")

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Начал работать с jQuery.
По нажатию кнопки у меня "всплывает" div поверх всех остальных элементов страницы, появление делаю так :

```
$(".upper_block").fadeIn(400);
$(".upper_block").css("display","block");
```

div появляется гладко и все ок , но при "растворении" возникают проблемы :

```
$(".upper_block").fadeOut(400);
$(".upper_block").css("display","none");
```

Растворение происходит сразу и полностью, а мне хотелось чтобы было плавно. Поэтому .css("display","none") не пишу.

Не вылезет ли мне это потом боком?) И возможно .fadeOut и .css() (которые в моем случае) делают одно и то же?)

P.S если что не ругайтесь, я всего лишь новичек)

Comment: `$(".upper_block").css("display","none");` это скрытие сразу, fadeOut - скрытие за определенное время, т.е. 400мс, в результате одно и то же.

Comment: не  надо display менять, fadeIn/FadeOut сам его меняет
http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/Ft9Tz/

Comment: всем спасибо)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В jQuery есть такие методы как .hide() и .show(), а также .fadeOut() и .fadeIn()

```
.hide() спрячем элемент сразу же, по сути это тоже самое что просто написать .css('display', 'none');

.show() аналогично hide, но наоборот тут же отобразит элемент. ПОЧТИ тоже самое что и .css('display', 'block'), но умнее. он смотрит окружение элемента и устанавливает ему нужное, будь то 'inline-block', 'table-row', 'block' или прочие..

.fadeOut('скорость', 'ускорение', 'callback ф-ция') - это анимированный аналог hide(), в который можно указать собственно скорость, easing-функцию (они же кривые бизье) и callback функцию которая будет вызвана по окончанию анимации. Пример:

$('#elem').fadeOut(400, 'swing', function(){
    alert('ахренеть, элемент исчез')
})

.fadeIn() - анимированный аналог show(), с тем же синтаксисом что и fadeout
```

Comment: @eicto нет, show() смотрит на стили. А вот у toggle() проперти.

Comment: @lampa http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/Ft9Tz/

там правда какая-то ерунда с inline/inline-block, превращается inline в inline-block, а так - запоминает.

Comment: show() и hide() тоже не так просты, у них есть параметр скорости и их анимация отличается от обычного display: none|block

Comment: @Dem, верно, но для новичка лучше разжевать. ".hide()" - в таком виде элемент спрячется мгновенно, однако если указать ".hide(350)" - элемент будет плавно уходить в прозрачность и через 350 миллисекунд спрячется полностью